# Converting multiple loops into one single loop with pagination

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, pagination

I am using [Isotope jquery plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) to filter/sort posts in Wordpress but to correctly filter the posts into the right order I have needed to output each category one after the other. To do this I've created one custom query for each category (4 categories in total, therefore 4 queries). You can see my working code here: http://pastebin.com/LTDmbbLf.

I would like to convert these 4 queries into just one query but this one query must display these 4 categories one after the other (like it does currently).

The reason why I want this, is because I'd like to add Infinite scroll functionality to grab the next batch of posts regardless of what category they are in. In order for this to work I need to add pagination and figured pagination wouldn't work correctly with 4 separate loops. However, if anyone can implement pagination into my existing code without having to re-write it then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category).

Use the examples part. Inside the foreach loop put your all the code which needs to be repeated for each category type.

something like:

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();

if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {

$my_query = new WP_Query('cat=$category->term_id');
```

//code to display category posts goes here

```
    }

}
?>
```

You are ready to go with this.

Comment: I do need to display specific stuff per category. Will what you've suggested work with this?

Comment: use the if condition inside the foreach so that you can do separate things for separate categories.

Comment: Ok so, I'm trying the if condition but i'm not getting anything returned, any ideas? I'm trying to get the id of the category: <?php if ( $categories == 3 ) { ?>
  This is a Brand category
 <?php } ?>

Comment: `<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
if($categories){
 foreach($categories as $category) {
  if($category->term_id == "some_id" ){
//do some category related stuff here
   }else if($category->term_id == "some_another_id" ){
//do some another category related stuff here
   }
.
.
.
.
.
//you can go to infinite possibilities in here
 }
}
?>`

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work either, here's my new code: http://pastebin.com/UjYj03em

Comment: If you try to use the `get_the_category()` function inside the_loop then you will get the categories related with single post only so use this function outside the_loop and save the result in some array and then use the same array inside the_loop to iterate for all the categories.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers but I have literally no idea how to do that. Is it cheeky to ask to see a the code so I can see how thats done? Thanks for your response though and I understand if you don't answer that last request. I'm not that great with PHP :(

Comment: Try this out. This might help you. http://pastebin.com/x9bRH2Uq

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get no output, even with your code. Sorry to report. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: try using some other values for comparison instead of term_id refer here: [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Return_Values)

Comment: No, I've tried cat_ID, category_nicename, cat_slug, cat_name but still I get not results.

Comment: Just did a var dump on $categories but it isn't grabbing any data...why would this be?